# Overcoming Creative Type - PRIVACY_CHECK_FAIL error

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to access video objects on the Facebook Marketing API, using their video_id. I've noticed that I can get the source url, if I can see the Creative Type (Video Page Post Ad). But for some ads, I seem to be blocked from access it - the Creative Type is PRIVACY_CHECK_FAIL.

Does anyone know who privacy settings I need to change to access the objects?

Comment: check the access_token  that you are used